# Retry after unrecoverable error in Azure IoT C SDK

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-reliability-features-in-sdks), the SDK does not reattempt a re-connection if it detects an unrecoverable error. However, in [the associated documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/doc/connection_and_messaging_reliability.md#) for the C SDK there is no mention of a recoverable or an unrecoverable error (or at least I have not found it there).

- How can I find out if the SDK is currently in a state where it might eventually recover or where it is required to manually reattempt a re-connection?
- If the retry policy decides not to reattempt a re-connection, is it possible to reconnect manually without destroying the device handle and creating a new one (for example with `IoTHubDeviceClient_CreateFromConnectionString`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `C SDK` currently doesn't distinguish between unrecoverable and recoverable errors from a retry perspective.
- All types of failures are dealt as recoverable failures that could potentially be recovered - so the documentation should be fixed to reflect current functionality `2018_11_20 release`.
- That said, the `SetConnectionStatusCallback` will return appropriate reason codes, which can help determine if the SDK should be allowed to retry or if a new connection needs to be established by the application.
- For instance, I would consider `IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONNECTION_BAD_CREDENTIAL` as an unrecoverable error for my application's device client.
- You are right - a new device handle needs to be created in order to re-attempt the connection manually. This is because all `C SDK APIs` key off this handle to query various device client states within `iothub_device_client`.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! And how can I set the `initial_wait_time_in_secs` then?

Comment: Currently, I see that it is hardcoded to either 1 second (exponential retry modes) or 5 seconds (other retry modes) because nothing else is setting the retry option named "RETRY_CONTROL_OPTION_INITIAL_WAIT_TIME_IN_SECS". If this is required to be exposed in specific scenarios, please file an issue on Github. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I have seen there is already an issue for this feature request: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/731